# Can a simple view be updated?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have a question regarding views. In a nut shell I have to update a field through a view.

A) Create a view which shows all car fields and option data for each car. Be sure all cars will show up.

```
create view carview as
select c.serial, c.cname, c.make, c.model, c.cyear, c.color, c.trim,
c.enginetype, c.purchinv, c.purchdate, c.purchfrom, c.purchcost, c.freightcost,
c.listprice, o.ocode, o.odesc, o.ocost, o.olist
from car c
join baseoption b
on c.serial = b.serial
join options o
on b.ocode = o.ocode
```

B) Have user C access the view and then assign permissions for the view to user C and have the user test the view. Query for just some of the fields. Update the year of a car and include the response in your submission.

```
GRANT ALL ON carview TO C;
```

The user C can access the view and do a select on it, but I don't know how to update the view with user C. (If that's even possible)

Comment: I would quibble with your definition of "simple view" here.  In my book, a simple view is a view over a single table.  Once we introduce choice or aggregations things aren't simple.

Comment: Your view may be [inherently updatable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54782).  Try `update carview set cyear = 2000;`, what happens?  Check `USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS`, and also check all the table definitions to see why it is or is not possible.  You may want to use a `left join` to include all cars.  And you should accept some of the answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I dislike updatable views but they are possible. You implement an INSTEAD OF trigger on the view:

http://psoug.org/reference/instead_of_trigger.html

And you can tailor it to only allow specific types of updates etc:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE <TRIGGER NAME>
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON <VIEW>
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    <UPDATE STATEMENT>; 
END <TRIGGER NAME>;
/
```